# Styling react native component - everything much too large when defined in pixels

Tags: ios, css, react-native

I'm building a react native app (no experience with iOS development until now) and I'm struggling with laying out correctly. The screen should look like this:

[image]

but instead it looks like this:
[image]

I've set the margins to the pixel size I'm after, but they seem much too large. Have I misunderstood something about the way react native does layout?

Code for this component:

```
import React, { Component, PropTypes } from 'react';
import {
  Text,
  View,
  Button,
  Image,
  TouchableHighlight,
  StyleSheet
} from 'react-native'

import Background from '../assets/background.png'
import SoundOn from '../assets/main_icon_sound.png'
import SoundOff from '../assets/main_icon_soundoff.png'
import imprintButton from '../assets/main_icon_imprint.png'
import storyButton from '../assets/main_icon_story.png'
import gameButton from '../assets/main_icon_game.png'

import Game from './Game'
import Imprint from './Imprint'
import Story from './Story'
import Sound from './Sound'

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  background: {
    height: 700, width: 700
  },
  soundButton: {
    marginLeft: 60, marginTop: 40
  },
  imprintButton: {
    marginLeft: 60, marginTop: 40
  },
  storyButton: {
    marginLeft: 382, marginBottom: 89
  },
  gameButton: {
    marginRight: 382, marginBottom: 89
  }
})

class MainMenu extends Component {
  static propTypes = {
    navigator: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <Image source={Background} resizeMode={Image.resizeMode.contain} style={styles.background}>
          <View style={{backgroundColor: 'rgba(0,0,0,0)'}}>
            <TouchableHighlight style={styles.soundButton}>
              <Image source={SoundOn} resizeMode={Image.resizeMode.contain}></Image>
            </TouchableHighlight>

            <TouchableHighlight style={styles.imprintButton}>
              <Image source={imprintButton}></Image>
            </TouchableHighlight>

            <TouchableHighlight style={styles.storyButton}>
              <Image source={storyButton}></Image>
            </TouchableHighlight>

            <TouchableHighlight style={styles.gameButton}>
              <Image source={gameButton}></Image>
            </TouchableHighlight>
          </View>
        </Image>
      </View>
    )
  }
}

export default MainMenu
```

Comment: is it possible to share repository with minimal code required to replicate this?

Comment: @Andreyco sure I've put up the started project since it only has one significant component: https://github.com/tomchambers2/graublaumiau

Answer (score 1):

for background image i would use flexbox and styles,

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    bgImageWrapper: {
        position: 'absolute',
        top: 0, bottom: 0, left: 0, right: 0
    },
    bgImage: {
        flex: 1,
        resizeMode: "stretch"
    },
});

<View style={styles.bgImageWrapper}>
    <Image source={require('image!background')} style={styles.bgImage} />
  </View>
  <Text> // yours code
    Welcome to React Native!
  </Text>
</View>
```

also for buttons you can use flexbox, paddings, margins because app will look different on real devices with their resolutions.

Comment: Thanks, that worked for the background. I still have no idea why the margins and image sizes are so out of proportion though.

What do you mean by use flexbox, paddings, margins - I'm already using those in the example?

Comment: i made example in gist : https://gist.github.com/wojteg1337/17416cb7dc42dec7c239d527ffa8c0a6

values wont be 1:1 in react native, because react native is scalling virtual pixels to device dimension. You need to find some scale which gonna look same like on the desing :)

Answer (score 0):

Basically the answer to this was that I didn't understand the difference between logical pixels and device pixels. My images were sized assuming a resolution of 2048, which made them twice as big as they ought to be of course.

After looking through various guides like [iosres](http://iosres.com) it started to make sense and I made normal device pixel sized images and @2x images from my originals.